# Partially consuming a cursor in multiple pl/sql calls without defining it in package spec

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I have a large source data set (a few million rows) that requires complex processing, resulting in much larger amount of data, which should be then offloaded and stored as files. The storage requires dividing up resulting data based on certain parameters, namely N source rows that meet certain criteria.

Since it's possible to compute the said parameters within PL/SQL, it was decided that the most efficient way would be to create a package, specify a spec-level cursor for source rows in it, then write a procedure that would partially consume the opened cursor until the criteria is meet and fill temporary tables with resulting data, which would then be offloaded, and the procedure would be called again, repeating until there's no more source rows. PL/SQL basically looks like this:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY generator as

  cursor glob_cur_body(cNo number) is
    select *
      from source_table
     where no = cNo
     order by conditions;

  procedure close_cur is
  begin
    if glob_cur_body%isopen then
      close glob_cur_body;
    end if;
  end close_cur;

  procedure open_cur(pNo number) is
  begin
    close_cur; 
    open glob_cur_body(pNo);
  end open_cur;

  function consume_cur return varchar2 is
    v source_table%rowtype;
    part_id varchar2(100);
  begin
    fetch glob_cur_body into v;
    if glob_cur_body%notfound then
      return null;
    end if;
    --Clear temporary tables
    --Do the processing until criteria is meet of there's no more rows
    --Fill the temporary tables and part_id
    return part_id;
  end consume_cur;
end generator;
```

And the consumer is doing the following (in pseudocode)

```
generator.open_cur;
part_id = generator.consume;
while ( part_id != null )
{
//offload data from temp tables
part_id = generator.consume;
}
generator.close_cur;
```

It's working fine, but unfortunately there's one problem: a spec-level cursor makes the package stateful, meaning that its recompilation results in `ORA-04068` for sessions that already accessed it before. It makes maintenance cumbersome, because there's a lot more to the package besides said functions, and it's actively used for unrelated purposes.

So, I want to get rid of the spec-level cursor, but I'm not sure if that's possible. Some ideas I've already discarded:

- Re-opening the cursor and skipping N rows: terrible performance, unreliable because affected by any changes to data made between opens
- Fetching the source cursor into plsql table: size too large.
- Filling up the entire unload tables at once, splitting them later: size too large, subpar performance.
- Opening the cursor as refcursor and storing refcursor variable in a dedicated package: impossible, as pl/sql doesn't allow sys_refcursor variables at spec levels
- Having `open_cur` procedures return refcursor, storing it in the offloader, and then somehow passing it to `consume_cur`: looked viable, but the offloader is in Java, and JDBC doesn't allow binding of `SYS_REFCURSOR` parameters.
- Changing `consume_cur` to pipelined function: could have worked, but oracle buffers pipelined rows, meaning it would execute multiple times when fetching data from it row-by-row. Also counterintuitive.

Only other idea I've had so far is to make a dedicated package storing said cursor, having `open` and `close` procedures and `get_cursor` returning refcursor; then call `get_cursor` from `generator.consume_cur`. That would make the dedicated package (which is unlikely to change) stateful and main package stateless. However, it seems like a half-baked patch rather than a problem solution. Is there a more decent way of achieving what I need? Perhaps changing the logic completely without affecting performance and storage limits too much.

Comment: Another idea is: don't recompile it so often. What is a reason of so frequent changes ? But if you really must, then maybe [Edition Based Redefinition](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_editions.htm#ADFNS020) could help.

Comment: I don't think making a dedicated package for the cursor is a half-baked idea at all - it follows basic Separation of Concerns. Like you said, this package is already doing an awful lot of unrelated things - it sounds like it needs to be refactored.

Answer (score 2):

I have a problem to understand your question. But I can provide clarification for your ideas.

1. > Opening the cursor as refcursor and storing refcursor variable in a
   >   dedicated package: impossible, as pl/sql doesn't allow sys_refcursor
   >   variables at spec levels

The workaround with `dbms_sql`.

```
create table test_rows as  (select level rr from dual connect by level <= 100);

create or replace package cursor_ctx is 
 ctx_number integer;
end;  


declare 
 p_cursor sys_refcursor;
begin
 open p_cursor for 'select rr from test_rows'; 
  cursor_ctx.ctx_number := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(p_cursor);
end;
```

This part consuming is data from the cursor.

```
declare 
 p_cursor sys_refcursor;
 type l_number is table of number;
 v_numbers l_number;
begin
  if  DBMS_SQL.IS_OPEN(cursor_ctx.ctx_number) then
    p_cursor := DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR(  cursor_ctx.ctx_number);
    fetch p_cursor bulk collect into v_numbers limit 10;
        if v_numbers.count < 10 then 
            dbms_output.put_line('No more data, close cursor');
            close p_cursor;
            cursor_ctx.ctx_number := null;
        else 
            cursor_ctx.ctx_number := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(p_cursor);
        end if;
        for i in nvl(v_numbers.first,1) .. nvl(v_numbers.last,-1) loop
            dbms_output.put_line(v_numbers(i));
           end loop;
    else 
     dbms_output.put_line('Null or cursor close ');
    end if;    
end;
```

1. Pipelined function has future to split input cursor into chunk. [Parallel Enabled Pipelined Table Functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions#parallel_enabled)
2. JDBC allows using sys_refcursor as an output parameter. `sys_refcursor = ResultSet`.

Comment: Oh, `DBMS_SQL` workaround is nice, never knew about it! Integer is much easier to pass around compared to refcursor. As for JDBC, I know that it supports output refcursor parameters, but I attempted to pass the same refcursor back as input parameter to another procedure, and JDBC doesn't allow it.